# Attempting to create string from a file

Tags: c#

Currently trying to create a string from a text file, however their seems to be an error preventing the stream reader from reading the text file correctly.

```
    private string testString = "Cheese";
    private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            fileName = openFileDialog.FileName;
            LoadFile();
        }
    }

    private void LoadFile()
    {
        String lineFromFile = "Chicken";
       *StringBuilder RawFileInput = new StringBuilder();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {

            while ((lineFromFile = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                RawFileInput.AppendLine(lineFromFile);
            }
        }*
        testString = lineFromFile; 
        testTB.Text = testString;

    }
```

The output should the code execute has the output textbox be empty, however should the block of code between the asterisks be commented out, the output textbox obviously displays the test phrase of Chicken. As such I'm pretty sure there is a problem with this particular block, however I can't seem to figure out what.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `RawFileInput.AppendLine(`?

Comment: Sounds like you want `File.ReadAllText()` as a rather simpler approach... but at the moment you're using the *final* value of `lineFromFile` and ignoring the unconventionally-named `RawFileInput` local variable's value after the loop...

Comment: Well you seem to append `lineFromFile` to `RawFileInput`, but you never use it anywhere. I suspect that you want `testString = RawFileInput.ToString();`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well your code, you are trying to set the testTB.Text with the text in your file. Taking that in account, shouldn't your last lines be:

```
    testString = RawFileInput.ToString(); 
    testTB.Text = testString;
```

You can achieve the same result with no need of a StringBuilder, replacing your whole LoadFile method with this line:

```
testTB.Text = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to read a document in entirety, like the following:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
using(var reader = new StreamReader(path))
     builder.Append(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

That would be the ideal, as it is more performant than `ReadAllText`.

> ReadToEnd works best when you need to read all the input from the
>   current position to the end of the stream. If more control is needed
>   over how many characters are read from the stream, use the
>   Read(Char[], Int32, Int32) method overload, which generally results in
>   better performance. ReadToEnd assumes that the stream knows when it
>   has reached an end. For interactive protocols in which the server
>   sends data only when you ask for it and does not close the connection,
>   ReadToEnd might block indefinitely because it does not reach an end,
>   and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting the contents of a file to populate a textbox, just set the Multiline property to true, and use `File.ReadAllLines()`

```
testTb.Lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
```